# App is in task manager but not visible

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, golang

I try to open [GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) and it shows up in task manager:

[image: Task manager]

But it doesn't show up in taskbar:

[image: Taskbar]

Also pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't show the app. Looks like the app is running but *not* visible. Did anybody run into such a problem?

### Update

A [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) did *not* help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got resolved by uninstalling the app, downloading the latest version, and installing it:

[image: App is visible now]